# What is a good alternative to and coffee?

Tags: ground-coffee

What product can increase dopamine levels in the brain quickly instead of caffeine ? 
Of course, I don't mean methamphetamine.

Comment: Ermmm - this _is_ Coffee SE, which means questions that _explicitly_ exclude coffee are sort of _implicitly_ off-topic, in my opinion.

Comment: @Stephie It all started here because roasted coffee contains acrylamide and it's a deadly poison, and unfortunately the coffee sales mafia in the world doesn't allow much information, so I have to use caffeine or green coffee pills. I do. But I thought I'd find a good alternative. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a beverage by the name of tea, also consumed hot with invigorating properties if choosing the correct varietea.

Comment: NO. COFFEE IS BETTER. SURE, TEA IS GOOD. BUT COFFEE. GRR